# How do I display multiple image filenames from MySQL on page

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo

I'm working on a small PHP program which stores/retrieves information from a MySQL DB and have hit a roadblock in displaying images. I can get a single image to display and I can see all images returned in an array but don't know where to go from there. Some background info:

My DB schema is pretty simple the table I'm using for images is named img_data and contains the following:

- ID (primary)
- serialnum (holds the serial of the item the image
  belongs to)
- file_name
- file_size
- file_type

Please take a look at the following related snippet of code:

```
     <?php
 $file_path = "http://localhost/test/image_uploads/$serial/";
 $sql= "SELECT img_data.file_name FROM img_data WHERE serialnum=:serial";
 $query = $DB->prepare( $sql );
 $query->bindParam(':serial', $serial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query->execute();
  $results = $query->fetchAll();
  ?>
   <?php foreach( $results as $row )
    $gimmeNewVal = str_replace(' ', '%20',$row['file_name']);
  $src=$file_path.$gimmeNewVal;
   $gimmeUrl = "<img src=".$src.">";
   echo $gimmeUrl;
   ?>
```

This code pulls the filename for each image belonging to the serial entered into a search form, turns it into the proper URL and displays the pic on the page for the 1st result. I'd like it to do this not for just the 1 image, but all images returned by the query. How do I approach the problem?

Now the following is the edited fixed and working code using suggestions by @paul though I used rawurlencode() over urlencode().

```
 <?php
 $file_path = "http://localhost/test/image_uploads/$serial/";
 $sql= "SELECT img_data.file_name FROM img_data WHERE serialnum=:serial";
 $query = $DB->prepare( $sql );
 $query->bindParam(':serial', $serial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query->execute();
  $results = $query->fetchAll();
  ?>
   <?php foreach( $results as $row ){
    $gimmeNewVal = rawurlencode($row['file_name']);
  $src=$file_path.$gimmeNewVal;
   $gimmeUrl = "<img src=".$src.">";
   echo $gimmeUrl;}
   ?>
```

Comment: Your `foreach` loop will only iterate the one line after it (`$gimmeNewVal = ...`). You need to wrap the entire block in `{ ... }` if you want to iterate more than that one line

Comment: Also, check out [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). It's a much better option than manually replacing spaces

Comment: Well that was a rather dumb oversight on my part. Thanks @phil. Good idea on the urlencode() as well.